# Problems accessing CSS from JSP Spring MVC

Tags: java, css, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am having some major problems trying to get my external css file to be read by my jsp files. My project structure at the moment is the following:

[image: Project Structure]

My spring.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"     
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"     
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- Uncomment and your base-package here: 
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.springframework.samples.web"/>  -->

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="model" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="controller" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="service" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="config" />
    <bean id="jspViewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

My JSP file:

```
  <link href="<c:url value="resources/css/main.css" />" rel="stylesheet">
```

I have tried alot of different kinds of paths and configurations but nothing seems to work.

Is there anyone who has any ideas what the issue seem to be ?

Would really appreciate any help.

Comment: think resources folder should be inside WEB-INF

Comment: Did not help, still not working, even tried adding a '/' before resources

Comment: It all depends on whether the web server sees the resources folder or not. try accessing it directly like http://example.com/resources/css/main.css